# Firestore NullPointerException on retrieve firebase.Timestamp.toDate (FieldValue.serverTimestamp update slow to update)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

After calling a `batch.commit` or `docRef.update` (part of it calls `FieldValue.serverTimeStamp` to update time of submission), I call `finish();` to go back to previous activity that loads a recycleView of the list of documents that was updated.

I get this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Date com.google.firebase.Timestamp.toDate()' on a null object reference`

I suspect it's that `FieldValue.servertimeStamp` takes more time to compute and the app crashes. However, the same field where recyclerView is pulling the datetime from already have an old value.

I'm not sure why the old value is not retrieved, but crashes on null instead.

**Q1) Does FieldValue.servertimeStamp make the field null until new datetime is computed?**

**My guess is, this particular call is waiting for an answer from Firebase server, thus taking more time but other calls are done locally first on the device before updating in the cloud. Some of your insights is appreciated.**

In the mean time, as a work-around to stop this asynchronous error, I have used a Thread loop with Thread.sleep while waiting for onCompleteSuccess to respond:

```
FirestoreFieldUpdated = false;
Thread myThread = new Thread(
     new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              try {
                     while (!FirestoreFieldUpdated) { //db.updateFields will change FirestorefieldUpdated to true uponSuccess
                           Thread.sleep(1000);
                     }
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                  } finally {
                       finish();
                  }
          }
     }
);
myThread.start();
```

**Q2) Is there a more elegant way or better way to do this? Or to enable synchronicity only for this particular transaction of updating datetime?**

**EDIT (added on more details on what I'm trying to do):**

I am trying to call this method from `AddNewOrder.java`:

```
public void updateFields(String actionDateField) {
    Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
    updates.put(actionDateField, FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
    updateSubmit.update(updates);
 }
```

from a class outside (`AddNewOrder.java`):

```
db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
db.updateFields("OrderDate");
finish();
```

`Finish();` will then pass me back to the previous activity that calls RecyclerView:

```
      Query query = mFirestore
            .collection("Org")
            .document(RootCollection)
            .collection("Stores")
            .document(StoreID)
            .collection("Orders")
            .whereGreaterThan("OrderVerified", "")
            .limit(queryLimit);
      mAdapter = new OrdersAdapter(query, FulfilmentActivity.this) {
        @Override
        protected void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            // Show a snackbar on errors
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                    "Error: check logs for info.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    mAdapter.setQuery(query);
    mOrdersRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mOrdersRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

In OrdersAdapter.java, I have this:

```
  Orders orders = snapshot.toObject(Orders.class);
  submitDate.setText(FORMAT.format(orders.getOrderDate()));
```

in `public void bind`.

The above is the line that NullPointerException appeared on.

Orders.java:

```
 public class Orders {
  private Timestamp OrderDate;
  public Orders(Timestamp orderDate) { this.OrderDate = orderDate; }
  public java.util.Date getOrderDate() { return OrderDate.toDate(); }
}
```

How do I fix this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

serverTimeStamp() indeed becomes Null in the cache before getting a confirm response from the server: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/192

Refer to this for solution: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Document

I fixed this by adding this:

```
DocumentSnapshot.ServerTimestampBehavior behavior = ESTIMATE;
Date date = snapshot.getDate("OrderDate", behavior);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're working with threading in order to deal with Firestore, you're almost certainly doing the wrong thing.  All Firestore APIs (actually, all Firebase APIs) are asynchronous, and require no threading on the part of your app.

Q1 - there is no intermediate null value in a document that's going to be created with a timestamp.  The server interprets the server timestamp token immediately and writes a Timestamp object to the document atomically.

Q2 - I can't really tell what you're trying to accomplish with this code.  It's way out of bounds of what you would normally do to write to Firestore.  If you want to know if a document has changed in Firestore, you attach a listener to a reference to that document, and the listener is invoked when the document is seen to change.  Again, there's no need for threading in this case, because the callbacks are all asynchronous.  As long as the listener is added, it will be called.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson 

I've added on what I'm trying to do in my post.

It's quite simple really. Update the time with server timestamp and then show it again on RecyclerView. It all loads up fine if there is a slight delay (in this case, my wrong threading usage).

Comment: I think I found the issue:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/192